# Spring MVC Ajax error 406

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble with simple ajax POST request. When I call doAjax on page load it returns me erorr 406 not acceptable. I have correct dependencies.

Simple model

```
package proj1.models;

public class Popravilo{
    public String id = null;
    public String name = null;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "car_list", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Popravilo showPopravila(){
        Popravilo p = new Popravilo();
        p.id="1";
        p.name ="p1";

        return p;
}
```

Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        doAjaxPost();
    });
    function doAjaxPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "car_list.htm",
            success: function(response) {
               console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


 <mvc:resources mapping="WEB-INF/resources/*" location="resources/"     cache-period="31556926"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="proj1.controllers"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>proj1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Error info
[image: Headers]

Comment: You need to specify header `Accept` in ajax call as `application/json`.

Comment: hm, i added that to ajax, but please look the headers, i posted image now

Comment: Server is returning content type `text/html` that's not correct as you are expecting `application/json`

Comment: Are you serving the content with `*.htm` extension ? `car_list.htm` is a relative URL, try specifying the absolute URL, you're probably getting error HTML page, also try setting the method to `GET` and hitting it from the browser.

Comment: well, in ajax i must have .htm in order to call correct mapping

Comment: We can see that i must change response headers. Which we are getting text/html now

Comment: You're not getting wrong headers, you're probably not even getting till service invocation. Your AJAX call is stopped somewhere in between by some security interceptor or probably URL is incorrect and thus error page is served with the `text/html` content.

Comment: Any idea what could possibly go wrong? I can provide more info..

Answer (score 1):

406 Not Acceptable means the resource for this request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request. So you need to specify the `Content-Type` as `application/json` which is what you are sending from server.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status `406` means that your client is not able to process the data returned by the server.

Try changing the ajax call as below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "car_list.htm",
    dataType: "json",/*changed the Accept header, acceptable datatypes*/
    success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    }
});
```